# Can't connect to local socketIO nodejs server on android

Tags: java, android, node.js, socket.io

I have made a basic nodejs server that console logs when a user connects to the server. i am using socket io for this because i wanna make a chat application. On my android side im trying to create a connection to this local server but i never get the console log when i try and socket.connected stays on false. also never get a error or something when trying to connect

I have tried some examples from the internet. i got 1 example working deleted everything that i didnt use and it still works. i copy paste from that example to my own project and still didn't work. 
This is the [example](https://github.com/fahidnasir/socket.io-android-sample/) i used.

Here is the code of my project
Node JS:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Android:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private Socket socket;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ChatApplication app = (ChatApplication) getApplication();
        socket = app.getSocket();
        socket.connect();
    }
}
```

ChatApplication class:

```
public class ChatApplication extends Application {
    private Socket mSocket;
    {
        try {
            mSocket = IO.socket("http://192.168.0.109:3000");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.toString());
        }
    }

    public Socket getSocket() {
        return mSocket;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the emulator to connect localhost?. Try with IP `10.0.2.2`

Comment: not using emulator. i am using my own android device

Comment: What is the error you're getting while connecting to the socket?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio emulator usually prevents localhost connections, I'm not sure if this happened in your case, but it has happened to me. Try popping out your `Logcat` in Android Studio and see if you can find something that indicates that the localhost connection got denied.

Not sure if this is it, but you should check.